# Is there any way to get the python souce code from an exe file made from pyinstaller

Tags: python, encryption, passwords, pyinstaller, exe

I am making a password manager in python but I thought of putting the hashes of the master password or the security keys directly into the program then I will convert it into an exe and use it.
So my question is that after converting it to the exe using the pyinstaller or py2exe module will any one be able to reconvert it backwards into python code and see it or will my python code be seeable after converting it to the exe.
I know what I am doing is not a good practice but it was also out of my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they almost certainly will.

To create the `exe`, PyInstaller basically compiles your files to `.pyc` files, bundles them with any other resources. When you run the file, it extracts them to a temporary folder and runs them. You can learn more about that process from [the docs for PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html). Someone that knows what they're doing can look at all those extracted files while the application is running, or just extract it themselves using a tool like [`pyinstxtractor`](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor). The strings for the hashes themselves will still appear in the `.pyc` files, and someone who knows what kind of pattern to look for can probably find them without too much trouble.

If you want to look into some options to make it more difficult, you [could explore some suggested options from PyInstaller such as compiling to Cython or adding a key](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#hiding-the-source-code).

But if you're only storing the hashes, they can only get the hashes. Whether or not they can derive the original key depends on the hashing algorithm you use.

Comment: I also know that but I am a little bit into cyber security so if any hachers come in and brute force my hashes then any thing can happen or is there anyway that you can tell me to securely store my hashes